# How to update all keys in MongoDB from a dictionary?

Tags: c#, mongodb, dictionary

I have some object:

```
public class ObjA
{
    [BsonElement("_id")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    
    [BsonElement("languages")]  
    public Dictionary<string, ObjB> languages { get; set; }
}

public class ObjB
{
    [BsonElement("translation_1")]
    public string Translation_1 { get; set; }
    
    [BsonElement("translation_2")]
    public string Translation_2 { get; set; }
    
    [BsonElement("translation_3")]
    public string Translation_3 { get; set; }
}
```

There are situations where I need to update `Translation_1` property of `ObjB` for every key in `languages` property of `ObjA` object.

Value of `key` of `languages` dictionary is not the same for all `ObjA`.

*So, query should update all `Translation_1` properties regardless of the key*

Update:
So far I have not made any significant progress:

```
UpdateDefinition<ObjA> update = Builders<ObjA>.Update.Set("languages.-key-.translation_1", newValue);
var result = await Collection.UpdateManyAsync(x => x.Id == someID, update);
```

Comment: can you show us your attempt?

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I have made an update, but it is not much that I have been able to figure out

Comment: This update will require the usage of [Updates with Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/). And, you can make use of the aggregation operator `$objectToArray` to get all the key-value pairs as an array, of which you can update the `Translation_1` specific property (for all properties of the languages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are situations where I need to update Translation_1 property of
> ObjB for every key in languages property of ObjA object.

Here is the Update with Aggregation Pipeline code, the first one is the `mongo` shell version and the second the C# version. The update modifies the value of the property `translation_1` of `ObjB`, for all keys of the `languages` dictionary property of `ObjA`.

```
var NEW_VALUE = "some new value"
var someId = "some id value"

db.test.updateOne(
  { _id: someId },
  [
    { 
        $set: { 
            languages: {
                $map: {
                     input: { $objectToArray: "$languages" }, 
                     as: "ele",
                     in: {
                         $mergeObjects: [ 
                             "$$ele", 
                             { "v": { 
                                  "translation_1": NEW_VALUE, 
                                  "translation_2": "$$ele.v.translation_2",
                                  "translation_3": "$$ele.v.translation_3" 
                        } }  ]
                     }
                }
            } 
    }},
    { 
        $set: { 
            languages: {
                $arrayToObject: "$languages" 
            }
    }},
  ]
)
```

```
var pipeline = new BsonDocumentStagePipelineDefinition<ObjA, ObjA>(
                         new[] { 
                             new BsonDocument("$set", 
                                 new BsonDocument("languages", 
                                     new BsonDocument("$map", 
                                          new BsonDocument {
                                              { "input", new BsonDocument("$objectToArray", "$languages") }, 
                                              { "as", "ele" }, 
                                              { "in", 
                                                     new BsonDocument("$mergeObjects", 
                                                         new BsonArray {
                                                             "$$ele",
                                                                  new BsonDocument("v", 
                                                                      new BsonDocument {
                                                                          { "translation_1", NEW_VALUE },
                                                                          { "translation_2", "$$ele.v.translation_2" },
                                                                          { "translation_3", "$$ele.v.translation_3" }
                                                                  })
                                              }) }
                                          }
                             ))),
                             new BsonDocument("$set", 
                                 new BsonDocument("languages", 
                                     new BsonDocument("$arrayToObject", "$languages")
                             ))
                         } 
);

System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<ObjA, bool>> filter = x => x.id == someId;
var update = new PipelineUpdateDefinition<ObjA>(pipeline);
var result =  collection.UpdateOne<ObjA>(filter, update);
```